# Disable ASP.NET balloon popup

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to disable that annoying balloon notification that pops up when you start an asp.net application? Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: annoying balloon notification]

http://i41.tinypic.com/2prd3b7.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked through the VS and built-in server settings and don't see anyway to disable it so I don't believe it is possible. You could [disable ALL balloon tips](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307729) instead.

Comment: that's too bad you can't disable it, but oh well, it's not a deal breaker, just an annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

Use IIS to run/debug your applications instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could go look through the Cassini source code and see what triggers that (the "ASP.NET Development Server" in VS is still based on the old Cassini web server).

Besides, I wouldn't stop the popup, because you may need to note the port number sometime.

Comment: I'll try and take a look at that, but the tooltip still shows the port number so it's available there.